# What does it mean to have (or not have) convicing evidence in statistics?

Tags: confidence-interval

I know how to calculate the confidence intervals for proportions and means at various confidence levels.

I'm having trouble when I'm asked to say whether there is (or isn't) convincing evidence as to whether a claim is true.

The question does not require knowledge of hypothesis testing, so I have to say whether there is (or isn't) convincing evidence that a claim is true using the confidence interval. In other words, I have to use the confidence interval to evaluate a claim.

For example, I have a confidence interval of (0.5, 0.6) at the 95% confidence level for some proportion. If someone claims that the proportion (of apples falling from a tree or something) is more than 0.55, how do I know whether there is (or isn't) convincing evidence that this claim is true?

Another question. Confidence level is 95% and confidence interval is (0.5, 0.6) for some proportion. Someone claims that the true proportion (of getting into a car accident or something) is more than 0.3. How do I know whether there is (or isn't) convincing evidence that this claim is true?

Yet another question. Let's say confidence level is 95% and confidence interval is (10, 15) for some mean. Someone claims that the true mean is different than 12. How do I know whether there is (or isn't) convincing evidence that this claim is true?

Another one. Let's say confidence level is 95% and confidence interval is (10, 15) for some mean. Someone claims that the true mean is 12. How do I know whether there is (or isn't) convincing evidence that this claim is true?

Statistics is, I think, a very carefully worded subject. What the "convincing" evidence exactly mean? Does it mean that there's "enough" evidence?

And another question. Does statistically significant mean that the value I'm looking at is "significantly different" from what I would normally get (values in the confidence interval)?

I apologize for asking so many questions at once. I've been grappling with these concepts for too long that I gave up and decided to post the questions here.

Answer (score 3):

The word "convincing" is not standard statistical wording, but rather subjective. You may have a lecturer who taught you how to use it, but that would be their personal usage really. Some people use specific different wordings depending on the test or confidence level, i.e., "there's some evidence that a mean is not 0" if it is rejected at 5% or - equivalently - it isn't in the 95% confidence interval (CI), "strong evidence" at 1%/99% etc. Probably you were taught to use "convincing" for a certain level, but that's not a standard.

What can be said is that the CI is a set of parameter values that are all compatible with the data (at the given level). So for example if the CI is (10,15), surely there can't be "convincing evidence" that the mean is 12, because it might well be 13 or 10.2 or 14.8. Same if the CI is (0.5,0.6), the true mean can well be 0.52, so this doesn't give you evidence that it's >0.55. However, means lower 0.3 would, at level 95%, *not* be compatible with the data, so yes, one can say there's evidence (with whatever additional word your lecturer would like to use) that the true mean is larger than 0.3.

"Significant" would normally refer to significance tests, however there is a mathematical correspondence between tests and CIs, so if the 95% CI is (0.5,0.6), this also means that a standard 5% test of the null hypothesis mean=0.3 would be rejected, so the mean is significantly different from 0.3.

However we've got to be careful not to put too much trust in words. For example, if you compute 100 CIs at level 95%, chances are on average 5 of them will not include the true value, so one shouldn't say every single one provides "convincing" or "enough" evidence - one shouldn't be too convinced that they *all* cover the true value. And then all this is based on model assumptions which in reality are not normally true (one may wonder whether a "true" mean that is not directly observable even exists), and then there's more than one way to test the same hypothesis and different tests may give you different results. Sorry for making things even more confusing but you've got to accept, indeed, statistics is difficult (and asking questions like you do is a good start).